# JBoss maven archtype: webapp-ear deployment issue

Tags: maven, deployment, jboss7.x, ear

I used the maven archetype "org.jboss.spec.archetypes:jboss-javaee6-webapp-ear-archetype" to generate the code. I started JBoss 7 and then tried to deploy from project root.

```
mvn package
mvn jboss-as:deploy
```

Packaging was successful.

But, I'm getting the following error message in the deployment stage:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myProject-web: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   com.example:myProject-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact
>   com.example:myProject-ejb:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

I tried packaging from both project root and myProject-ear folders.

My environment: ubuntu 12.04, Oracle JDK 7, JBoss 7.1, Maven 3

Thank you very much!

This is my project structure after packaging (some parts omitted)

```
.
├── myProject-ear
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main
│   │       └── application
│   │           └── META-INF
│   │               └── myProject-ds.xml
│   └── target
│       ├── application.xml
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       │   └── pom.properties
│       ├── myProject
│       │   ├── META-INF
│       │   │   ├── application.xml
│       │   │   └── myProject-ds.xml
│       │   ├── myProject-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar => *** EJB JAR HAS GENERATED ***
│       │   └── myProject-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war => *** WAR HAS GENERATED ***
│       └── myProject.ear                      => *** EAR HAS GENERATED (contains other 2 archives) ***
├── myProject-ejb
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   └── target
│       ├── classes
│       │   ├── com
│       │   ├── import.sql
│       │   └── META-INF
│       │       ├── beans.xml
│       │       └── persistence.xml
│       ├── generated-sources
│       │   ├── annotations
│       │   └── test-annotations
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       │   └── pom.properties
│       ├── myProject-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar    => *** EJB JAR HAS GENERATED ***
│       └── test-classes
│           ├── arquillian.xml
│           ├── com
│           │   └── example
│           │       └── test
│           │           └── MemberRegistrationTest.class
│           ├── META-INF
│           │   └── test-persistence.xml
│           └── test-ds.xml
├── myProject-web
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   └── target
│       ├── classes
│       │   └── com
│       ├── generated-sources
│       │   └── annotations
│       ├── maven-archiver
│       │   └── pom.properties
│       ├── myProject-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT
│       │   ├── index.html
│       │   ├── META-INF
│       │   ├── resources
│       │   └── WEB-INF
│       │       ├── beans.xml
│       │       ├── classes
│       │       │   └── com
│       │       │       └── example
│       │       ├── faces-config.xml
│       │       └── templates
│       │           └── default.xhtml
│       ├── myProject-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war => ***WAR HAS GENERATED***
│       └── surefire
├── pom.xml
└── README.md
}
```

Comment: Wich version of `org.jboss.spec.archetypes:jboss-javaee6-webapp-ear-archetype`? BTW: Did you seated the tree structure by hand or used a tool for this?

Comment: I used linux 'tree' command. Thanks for your response. I figured out the answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

After attempting some more I figured out following works:

```
mvn clean package jboss-as:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add below lines in setting.xml file of .m2 directory then restart your IDE.**

```
<profiles>        
    <profile>
        <id>maven-profile</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>MavenCentral-1</id>
                <name>Maven Central Repository 1</name>
                <releases>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>                    
                <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>MavenCentral-2</id>
                <name>Maven Central Repository 2</name>
                <releases>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>                    
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>jboss-public-repository-group-1</id>
                <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
                <releases>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>                    
                <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```